# running buildout causes content to be removed

Tags: plone, buildout

I need to install some new add-on's to my Plone site using buildout but when I run buildout any content on the site that has been created since the last buildout and has a seperate theme is no longer visible. The top level folder is visible in the ZMI but when I click on it it states that the page does not exist. I'm a novice at this so any ideas would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. **Start Plone in the foreground** (via bin/instance fg), then look for errors and fix them.

-OR-

1. **Remove the add-ons** (from buildout.cfg), run Buildout again, restart Plone.

The latter *should* restore your Plone installation to it's previously-known-good configuration.